# Elixir Enum.max returns last instead of first element

Tags: elixir

> If multiple elements are considered maximal, the first one that was found is returned.
>   https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#max/2

```
iex> [4, 0, 4] |> Enum.with_index |> Enum.max
{4, 2}
```

I would have expected that this returns `{4, 0}`, obviously I'm missing something?

Thanks for any help to clear up my confusion :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because after `|> Enum.with_index`, your list is `[{4, 0}, {0, 1}, {4, 2}]` and `{4, 2}` is greater than `{4, 0}` as when comparing tuples, when the first element is equal, the second (and then third and so on) elements are compared.

A correct way to test what you were trying to test would be to use `Enum.max_by/2` instead like this:

```
iex(1)> [4, 0, 4] |> Enum.with_index |> Enum.max_by(fn {x, i} -> x end)
{4, 0}
```